# using selenium grid for testing

Tags: eclipse, selenium-grid

Trying to run the code but getting this error:

> Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the 
>      remote server or browser start-up failure.
>      Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>      As i am beginner i don't know whats the exact issue .so please help me.

I am using Windows cmd for creating the hub and node connection.

```
public class Grid_2 {
    WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl,nodeURL;
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
        baseUrl="https://www.google.co.in";
        nodeURL="http://192.168.0.10:5566/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capability=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capability.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
        driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL),capability);
    }
    @AfterTest
        public void afterTest(){
        driver.quit();
    }
    @Test
        public void simpleTest(){
            driver.get(baseUrl);
            Assert.assertEquals("google", driver.getTitle());
    }
        }
```

Comment: Someone pls help

Comment: Have you looked at the node logs ? I am guessing that you are perhaps missing the `geckodriver` binary in the PATH variable and that's why your test is crashing.